# Grails Command Object nullable constraint

Tags: grails, grails-validation, command-objects

I recently upgraded a 1.3.6 application to Grails2. My test cases have started failing

Here is the scenario, I have a command object and a constraint. When the request hits the action, without the parameter `name` (`localhost:8080/app-name/Book/test?i=0`) 
I am getting a validation error. Grails doc says Command Object fields are nullable by default. Looks like it is not, from this test. My question is how do I make them nullable true globally for all command objects? Code below,

```
class BookController {

    def test = {TestCommand cmd ->
        cmd.validate()
        if (cmd.hasErrors()) {
            println "has Errors"
            render 'Error'
        } else {
            println "Success"
            render 'Hello World'
        }
    }
}
```

Command Object is :

```
class TestCommand {
       int i;
       String name

       static constraints = {
         name(password: true)
       }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be a Grails bug. Grails 2.0 has changed behaviour about default nullable value for Command Objects. Here is the [JIRA](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8580)